# Is there anyway to send a json array to server side php and insert it's values in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, angular8

i am using ANgular 8 in client side and PHP 7 in server side .
i had problem to use the values of that array to insert them by query .

i displayed the array by print_r and it show something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idprod] => 8
            [prix] => 2
            [qte] => 1
            [refCmd] => 35
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [idprod] => 9
            [prix] => 2.4
            [qte] => 5
            [refCmd] => 35
        )

)
```

the question is how to insert every object of that array in table called regrouper ?

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content- 
Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json);

$tab = $decoded->tab;
function conn()
{
$dbhost = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "smart";
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smart', $user, $pass);
return $conn;
}
$db = conn();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO regrouper (refCommande, refProduit, prixP, 
qteP) VALUES(:refCmd,:refProduit,:prix,qte)");
foreach ($tab as $item) {
$p->execute([json_decode($item)]);
}
echo json_encode(true);
?>
```

i expect the table regrouper to have the first object on a row and the second object in another row

Comment: you load `->execute($item)` instead, and another problem that you have `?` 5 question mark placeholders, but in your `print_r` dump each batch of array only has 4. the execution will not work

Comment: You need to convert the objects to arrays.

Comment: *"Is there anyway to send a json array to server side php and insert it's values in a table?"* Using MySQL's 8 [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) would be a valid option aswell??  more or less like  `INSERT INTO table <columns> SELECT <columns> FROM(SELECT <columns> FROM JSON_TABLE(...)`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I misunderstood what you were suggesting.

Comment: *"Everything I've seen about using MySQL's JSON datatype recommends against using it. "* ,  *"I misunderstood what you were suggesting"* @Barmar No problem but i agree JSON datatype storage could ideally be better implemented as binairy JSON or by the binairy storage spec [EXI4JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/exi-for-json/) which w3c has defined...

Comment: @RaymondNijland AAUI, MySQL does implement the JSON datatype using a compact, binary format, it doesn't just store strings. My issue with it is the functions for using it are complicated and limited, and it encourages denormalized schemas (e.g. putting JSON arrays into columns).

Comment: *"AAUI, MySQL does implement the JSON datatype using a compact, binary format, it doesn't just store strings."* what did i say about time to get coffee i believe @Barmar seams i am starting mixing RDMS's up now [MariaDB JSON datatype ("JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT")](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/) ... *"My issue with it is the functions for using it are complicated and limited, and it encourages denormalized schemas (e.g. putting JSON arrays into columns). "* Point taken well MySQL 8 JSON_TABLE() makes it more useable..

Comment: Yes, that looks like a useful function. It's all the stuff for dealing with JSON datatypes that's a mess.

Comment: *"Yes, that looks like a useful function. It's all the stuff for dealing with JSON datatypes that's a mess. "* Yes @Barmar i know what you mean, i once  wrote a answer where i ["emulated" JSON_TABLE()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328994/2548147)  in older MySQL versions.. Needed SQL becomes trickly really fast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `json_decode()` twice. You already decoded it when you did

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
```

so you don't need to use `json_decode($item)` when inserting.

Use the `true` second argument to `json_decode()` so that it creates an associative array instead of an object for each item. Then you can pass that array to `$p->execute()` directly. You also need to use `$decoded['tab']` instead of `$decoded->tab`.

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content- 
Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

$tab = $decoded['tab'];
function conn()
{
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "smart";
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smart', $user, $pass);
    return $conn;
}
$db = conn();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO regrouper (refCommande, refProduit, prixP, qteP)
                   VALUES(:refCmd,:refProduit,:prix,qte)");
foreach ($tab as $item) {
    $p->execute($item);
}
echo json_encode(true);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198695/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-is-there-anyway-to-send-a-json-array-to-server-si).