# Not able to transfer angular array list to php script for insert into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, angular

From angular trying to insert excel sheet data in mysql database table using php script. I have installed `xlsx` in angular then trying to read xlsx sheet.

Below is my CandidateuploadComponent.ts class

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'; 
export class CandidateuploadComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private userSvc: AddUsersService,private route: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
}
title = 'XlsRead';
file:File
arrayBuffer:any
filelist:any

addfile(event)     
{    
  this.file= event.target.files[0];     
  let fileReader = new FileReader();    
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);     
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {    
  this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;    
  var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);    
  var arr = new Array();    
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);    
  var bstr = arr.join("");    
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});    
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];    
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];    
  console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));    
        var arraylist = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});     
        this.filelist = [];    
        let usersJson: any[] = arraylist;
 // Sends the form data to the service
  this.userSvc.sendFormData(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true})).subscribe(
  response => console.log("Success! ", response)
  // error => console.error("Error: ", error)
  );
       
  }    

  }       

  }
```

service class

```
sendFormData(userData) {
console.log('hi');
console.log(userData);
return this.http.post("http://localhost:8088/post_candidateDetails.php", userData);
}
```

Belwo is php.script

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content-Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$tab = $decoded['tab'];
function conn() {
  $dbhost = "**********";
  $user = "*****";
  $pass = "*****";
  $db = "*********";
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=******;dbname=******', $user, $pass);
  return $conn;
}
$db = conn();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                  
$p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetails(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email)VALUES(:EmployeeId,:FirstName,:LastName,:Mobile,:Email)");
                       
foreach ($tab as $item) {
  $p->execute($item);
}
echo json_encode(true);

?>
```

Below i am getting error in browser and postman differently, first error in browsers which is line number 9 in php script `undifine index: tab` and post man error : `<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php</b> on line <b>23</`

[image]

[image]

I refer this axample for php script:

[Is there anyway to send a json array to server side php and insert it's values in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701726/is-there-anyway-to-send-a-json-array-to-server-side-php-and-insert-its-values-i)

Getting error Undefined index: tab for inserting array list using php script
In service method i am getting json data as shown in above browser debug,  i am trying since a week not resolving still please help me to out this issue.

Updated PHP script as suggested Olivier answer.

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content-Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($decoded);

    function conn()
    {
        $dbhost = "************";
        $user = "*******";
        $pass = "*******";
        $db = "********";
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=*******;dbname=*******', $user, $pass);
        return $conn;
    }
    $db = conn();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                  
    $p = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO CandidateDetails(EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Mobile,Email)VALUES(:EmployeeId,:FirstName,:LastName,:Mobile,:Email)");
                       
    foreach ($decoded as $item) {
      $p->execute($item);
    }

    echo json_encode(true);

    ?>
```

output in browser with error after suggested by Olivier:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Employeeid] => 1
                [FirstName] => fn1
                [LastName] => ln1
                [Mobile] => 123456789
                [Email] => Email1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Employeeid] => 2
                [FirstName] => fn2
                [LastName] => ln2
                [Mobile] => 123456790
                [Email] => Email2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Employeeid] => 3
                [FirstName] => fn3
                [LastName] => ln3
                [Mobile] => 123456791
                [Email] => Email3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Employeeid] => 4
                [FirstName] => fn4
                [LastName] => ln4
                [Mobile] => 123456792
                [Email] => Email4
            )

    )
    <br />
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php:27
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php(27): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
    #1 {main}
      thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear. There is no `tab` item in your JSON data.

Comment: then what wrong, how to achieve.@Olivier

Comment: Is there any specific reason to read excel file on client side instead of reading on server side?

Comment: Also don't post your sensitive data like DB credentials on public forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message says that there is no `tab` item in the JSON data, which is perfectly normal since you don't send such an item.

The real problem is that you copy/pasted some code without really understanding what it does. The guy you took the code from is a French speaker, and the French word for "array" is "tableau", which is often abbreviated as "tab" in programs. So he obviously stored his array in a `tab` item.

But that's not what you are doing. You convert your array directly to JSON, which means `$decoded` is already the array. So you should do something like this instead:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($decoded as $item) {
    $p->bindValue(':EmployeeId', $item['Employeeid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $p->bindValue(':FirstName', $item['FirstName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $p->bindValue(':LastName', $item['LastName'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $p->bindValue(':Mobile', $item['Mobile'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $p->bindValue(':Email', $item['Email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $p->execute();
}
```

Comment: can you add complete answer because little confusion and i am send correctly from angular?. @Olivier

Comment: From you screenshot, Angular sends an array (with 4 elements). You don't need to change anything on that side. You should only change the PHP script (remove `$tab`).

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
true.... after removing this line  $tab = $decoded['tab'];. @Olivier

Comment: Did you also change the `foreach` line?

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php(43): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />

Comment: i have updated php scrpt in question please check and confirm , i am getting data in php using print.but error is coming:  Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php:43 Stack trace: #0  . @Olivier

Comment: The parameters are not set correctly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219453/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-olivier).

Comment: error: <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php:27 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php(27): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array) 
#1 {main} 
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post_candidateDetails.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />. @Olivier

Comment: now its working but two times array inserting in table.@Olivier.

Comment: Thanks its working only issue was tab and my excel sheet values miss matching thank i will update, your kind information if i will put this   foreach ($tab as $item) {
  $p->execute($item);
} its working fine. @Olivier