# MySQL JSON - Replace values if matches conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a JSON value using MySQL JSON functions (i.e. JSON_REPLACE, JSON_SEARCH, etc.), if the object containing the property matches some conditions.

i.e.:

```
create temporary table mytable(id int, `data` json);
insert into mytable values(1,
'
{
    "connection": {
            "title": "My Global Connection",
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 3306,
            "dbname": "sampledb",
            "username": "root",
            "password": "root"
    },
    "myobjects": [
            {
                "name": "MyObject 1",
                "connection": {
                        "title": "My Object 1 Connection",
                        "host": "localhost",
                        "port": 3306,
                        "dbname": "sampledb",
                        "username": "root",
                        "password": "root"
                }
            }
    ]
}
');
```

In this example I would to replace the fields `host`, `username`, `password` with values `myhost`, `myuser`, `mypass` for every object having `host = "localhost"`, `user = "root"` and `password = "root"`.

All the three conditions have to be satisfied simultaneously.

In this example I don't want the field `title` to change.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you use MySQL 8 or is upgrading to MySQL 8 a option? As [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) makes it so much more easy to use conditions  as JSON_TABLE parses the JSON data to SQL results..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: *"I'm using MySQL 5.7 "* Yes i assume you consider upgrading isn't a option?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, actually it is not possibile an upgrade at the moment, although your tip about JSON_TABLE is still interesting.

Comment: really consider upgrading as soon as possible as you would need to write/use tricky SQL as you have dynamic json array keys -> some answers which i posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/55359984/2548147  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328994/2548147

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your advice, I'll consider it for any other server I own (not this case unfortunately).